# How can I grab metrics from a clusterized instance of Kafka with Prometheus with JMX Exporter?

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, prometheus

Here is the current configurations.
Docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  prometheus:
    image: "prom/prometheus:latest"
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/prometheus.yml
    command: "--config.file=/prometheus.yml"
    container_name: prometheus

  jmx-kafka:
    image: "sscaling/jmx-prometheus-exporter"
    ports:
    - "5556:5556"
    environment:
      CONFIG_YML : "./config.yml"
    volumes:
    - ./config.yml:/config.yml
    container_name: jmx_kafka
    depends_on:
    - kafka

  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes`

  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    container_name: "kafka"
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9991
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-jmx.properties:/opt/bitnami/kafka/conf/kafka-jmx.properties
```

prometheus.yml

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 30s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'jmx-kafka'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['jmx-kafka:5556']
```

and
config.yml

```yaml
hostPort: jmx-kafka:5556
rules:
- pattern: "kafka.*"
```

I am using the jmx httpserver, not the agentjar. What is wrong with my configuration? I am not able to get any metrics from the jmx exporter. No data in docker's logs or prometheus. Prometheus does not show the port being up.

I have tried different configurations. I tried changing the following config.yml configuration.

```yaml
 lowercaseOutputName: true
 rules:
   - pattern: 'kafka.*'
     name: 'kafka-metrics'
     value:  'ValueToCollect'
     type: GAUGE
```

This allows me to access metrics on prometheus, but it did not scrape any metrics from my Kafka app.

Comment: Ideally, you do use the agent jar in the kafka container itself... Note: Strimzi can do this for you in Kubernetes, rather than Docker Compose

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your values have you configured anything to read from `kafka:9991`, which is the JMX server that you want to read metrics from and parse into Prometheus format.

Only the prometheus scrape configs should use `jmx-kafka:5556`, as that's the HTTP server where metrics would be exposed.

Comment: Do you mind going into a bit more detail? 
From what I understand, my config file should be looking at 9991 not 5556.
This is my first time working with these technologies, so I am a bit confused on how things are suppose to be connected. I am working on this project with a group and we have been stuck on prometheus for a couple days now. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do not have experience with the `sscaling/jmx-prometheus-exporter` image, but based on documentation, its config file needs to point at a JMX server, which is `hostPort: kafka:9991`. Notice the difference in ports 12345 and 9999 - https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter#running-the-standalone-http-server ; Or, like I said above, you could use minikube and Strimzi where this can all be automated. https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview#metrics-overview_str